# Unit-Test a Symfony FormType with custom data_class fails

Tags: php, forms, symfony, unit-testing

I want to start testing my forms with PHPUnit.
First I created a simple form.

```
final class LoginFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('password', PasswordType::class);
        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => LoginFormData::class
        ));
    }

}
```

I defined a data_class. This class will later perform validation etc. But for the moment this should be fine. I tested the form in the browser and it worked fine.
At the moment it is only 2 public properties.
"username" and "password".

After that i followed the docs https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/unit_testing.html

I then ended with this testcase.

```
function it_submits_valid_data()
    {
        $data = new LoginFormData();
        $data->username = 'John';
        $data->password = 'yoloyolooooo';

        $form = $this->factory->create(LoginFormType::class);

        $form->submit($data);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($data, $form->getData());
        $this->assertTrue($form->isValid());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;
        foreach (array_keys($data) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
```

But it does not work.
I'm getting the following error

There was 1 failure:

> Failed asserting
>   that false is true.

This happens at this line $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

If i adjust the form to use an array and pass in an array in the test it works fine.
What did I do wrong?

--- Edit 1

After Lugi Hauges answer i figured out that it throws an TransformationException somewhere.
(I didn't see it because it gets catched)

Since my form is a coumpound form

```
if (!is_array($submittedData)) {
    throw new TransformationFailedException('Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission.');
}
```

I didn't pass an array. So I now know where it throws.
But not why. I thought I can use Data-Objects do I have to implement a custom datamapper?
I thought this should not be neccesarry, since my properties are public.

--- Edit 2

Aaaah, I have to pass in an array. This array will get transformed to my data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an if condition in submit method like that:

```
        if (!is_array($submittedData)) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission.');
        }
```

and it's throws a `TransformationFailedException`. In catch block,

```
...
...
...
        } catch (TransformationFailedException $e) {
            $this->transformationFailure = $e;

            // If $viewData was not yet set, set it to $submittedData so that
            // the erroneous data is accessible on the form.
            // Forms that inherit data never set any data, because the getters
            // forward to the parent form's getters anyway.
            if (null === $viewData && !$this->config->getInheritData()) {
                $viewData = $submittedData;
            }
        }
```

as you see, `$e` assigning to `$this->transformationFailure`

```
public function isSynchronized()
{
    return null === $this->transformationFailure;
}
```

when you call `isSynchronized` method, it returns `false` because `transformationFailure`'s value not identical to `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot you helped me a lot.
Since the Exception is beeing catched I did not see it at all.